# Select value from a table name where table name is stored as a value in column in some other table using dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to fetch a value for `NULL` column value. The corresponding value is stored in a different table. This table name is in the same table from which I am trying to fetch

```
ID  | ColumnName1 | ColumnName2 | ColumnNam3
____________________________________________
1      ABC           TableName1    RecordId1
2      PQR           TableName1    RecordID2
3      NULL          TableName1    RecordId3
4      NULL          TableName2    RecordId1
5      STU           TableName2    RecordId2
```

So my select query is

```
Select ColumnName1 from Table
```

Which is the result

```
ID  | ColumnName1 | ColumnName2 | ColumnNam3
    ____________________________________________
    1      ABC           TableName1    RecordId1
    2      PQR           TableName1    RecordID2
    3      NULL          TableName1    RecordId3
    4      NULL          TableName2    RecordId1
    5      STU           TableName2    RecordId2
```

Is it possible to achieve the below?

```
 Select 
       CASE WHEN ColumnName1 is NULL 
        then SELECT ColumnName1 From ColumnName2 Where RecordId = ColumnName3 
       ELSE COlumnName1 AS 
ColumnNullFilled END
```

Ohh, I already tried dynamic sql like

```
Declare @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SqlQuery = N'Select  CASE WHEN ColumnName1 is NULL 
            then SELECT ColumnName1 From ColumnName2 Where RecordId = ColumnName3 
           ELSE COlumnName1 AS 
    ColumnNullFilled1 END 
  Case when ColumnNameSOmeother is NULL
    then SELECT ColumnNameSOmeother  From ColumnName2 Where RecordId = ColumnName3 
           ELSE ColumnNameSOmeother AS 
    ColumnNullFilled2 END  

...
ColumnNameN
FROM Table'

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlQuery;
```

It does not execute, but only prints columnname2 and columnname3 instead of columnvalues.

For note: I have created a SP that fetches the records based on the columnname2 and ColumnName2 as parameters, which gives the result but does not work with dynamic SQL.

I also tried user defined function, which I am not sure if there is any other way. Here not only 3 records but I am talking about 1000 records and every record has a value in some other table if its null.

Sorry, normalization wasn't done previously by other developer and I cannot go back and change the architecture. Also, the application becomes too heavy if I do it for not just one column but same scenario for different other columns too. (ColumnNameX).

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: As you say, you need dynamic SQL... give it a go and ask a question when stuck.

Comment: Ideally rethink your design; this type of design never scales and it far from easy to work with. Use an approach that does not mandate dynamic SQL.

Comment: `THEN (SELECT ColumnName1 FROM ColumnName2)` but this only runs when `ColumnName1` is null, so you're still going to return null.

Comment: @DaleK  from columnName2 value is tablename1 , and columnname1 if null is then should come from the tablename which is mentioned in the columnname2

Comment: @Larnu true that and I agree, but as I told you , going back to normalize the architecture is something I am restricted to

Comment: Better doing it now that later though. Every query you'll going to need to do is going to be dynamic. If you're not familiar with that (which you appear not be be, or you wouldn't be asking) that is going to be impossible for you to debug when you get errors. Also poorly written dynamic SQL is a easy way to introduce huge security vulnerabilities into your application. If you can redesign, then do.

Comment: @JijoNair I understand that, but your code is selecting ColumnName1 from the second table, but ColumnName1 is null, so you won't select a column.

Comment: @DaleK Ohh, no in this case we have a value in the tablename1 and I want to print that value in the main select query

Comment: Look at your query though, and sample data, you don't specify within your sample data the column to pull the data from tablename1, `SELECT ColumnName1 From ColumnName2 Where RecordId = ColumnName3 ` this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Although you're executing a sql string, I don't see anything *dynamic* about your sql, which is equally as flawed as if you tried it directly. I must be misunderstanding your question as I can't see any need for dynamic sql, youy outer join both tables and use `isnull`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your requirement, could you not just outer-join both tables and either `isnull` the column from both tables or use `case` to determine which column to use?

```
select IsNull(t1.columnName1, t2.columnName1) as Result
from MyTable t
left join Tablename1 t1 on t1.recordId=ColumnNam3
left join Tablename2 t2 on t2.recordId=ColumnNam3
where <criteria>
```

or

```
select case ColumnName2
        when 'TableName1' then t1.ColumnName1 else t2.ColumnName1 end as Result
from MyTable t
left join Tablename1 t1 on t1.recordId=ColumnNam3
left join Tablename2 t2 on t2.recordId=ColumnNam3
where <criteria>
```

Comment: Hi. No , so actually these table names are ambiguous...can be anything but not specific

Comment: @JijoNair . . . This looks like the right answer to me (although I prefer `coalesce()`.  You should not be storing table names in columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

(I included the code to create some test data like in your example)

The actual statement generation is at the bottom.

Basically, this dynamically generates an SQL statement that does left joins on all referenced tables. However, please beware that left joins cause a significant performance problem if there are a lot of them and there are a lot of rows in your tables. In that case I would suggest to rethink your design. For example, split the column ColumnName2 & 3 into several columns...

```
-- CREATE TEST DATA
create table [Table] (
    [ID] int not null,
    [ColumnName1] varchar(16) null,
    [ColumnName2] sysname not null,
    [ColumnName3] varchar(16) not null
);
go
create table [TableName1] (
    [ColumnName1] varchar(16) null,
    [RecordId] varchar(16) not null
);
go
create table [TableName2] (
    [ColumnName1] varchar(16) null,
    [RecordId] varchar(16) not null
);
go
insert into [Table] ( [ID], [ColumnName1], [ColumnName2], [ColumnName3] )
values
    ( 1, 'ABC', 'TableName1', 'RecordId1' ),
    ( 2, 'PQR', 'TableName1', 'RecordID2' ),
    ( 3, NULL,  'TableName1', 'RecordId3' ),
    ( 4, NULL,  'TableName2', 'RecordId1' ),
    ( 5, 'STU', 'TableName2', 'RecordId2' );
insert into [TableName1] ( [ColumnName1], [RecordId] )
values
    ( '111', 'RecordId1' ),
    ( '222', 'RecordID2' ),
    ( '333', 'RecordId3' );
insert into [TableName2] ( [ColumnName1], [RecordId] )
values
    ( 'one', 'RecordId1' ),
    ( 'two', 'RecordId2' );
go

-- ACTUAL CODE
declare @joinSql nvarchar(max) = N'';
select @joinSql = @joinSql+N'
left join ['+REPLACE([ColumnName2], N']', N'[]]')+N'] on
    [base].[ColumnName2] = N'''+REPLACE([ColumnName2], N'''', N'''''')+N''' and
    ['+REPLACE([ColumnName2], N']', N'[]]')+N'].[RecordId] = [base].[ColumnName3]'
from ( select distinct [ColumnName2] from [Table] ) as [distinct];

declare @caseSql nvarchar(max) = N'';
select @caseSql = @caseSql+N', ['+REPLACE([ColumnName2], N']', N'[]]')+N'].[ColumnName1]'
from ( select distinct [ColumnName2] from [Table] ) as [distinct];

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'
select
    [base].[ID],
    COALESCE([base].[ColumnName1]'+@caseSql+N') [ColumnName1],
    [base].[ColumnName2],
    [base].[ColumnName3]
from [Table] as [base]'+@joinSql+N';';
print @sql;
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: interesting. I will try this query and hopefully it will fit.

Comment: Note, syntax like `'[' = {Some String} + ']'` is *not* injection safe. Quote your dynamic objects properly with `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: yes, you are right, closing brackets need to be escaped Main reason I originally did not, is that in environments where you store table/column names there should never ever enter any user input, BUT I totally agree, for production you should definitely play it safe!